# Does Openshift Origin SAML?

Tags: single-sign-on, openshift, saml, openshift-origin

I was looking into the OpenShift Origin documentation but didn't get any information whether SAML is supported by the OpenShift Origin.

Can any one give me some lead to this topic or provide some reference link?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

SAML is not officially supported, however, SAML integration is possible using Apache and `mod_auth_mellon` in combination with the [RequestHeaderIdentityProvider](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#RequestHeaderIdentityProvider).

OpenShift provides a full working example for the purpose of SAML integration: https://github.com/openshift/request-header-saml-service-provider